# I don't get auto quotes in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to python. I am using Jupyter notebook through anaconda.
I do not get the auto quotes while writing code.("",'')
But auto braces or parentheses works.
Could you please help me fix this.

Answer (score 6):

It's part of the "Auto Close Brackets" setting, which is a toggle menu item that you should be able to find in the "Settings" menu.

Comment: you saved 1000 hours!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your keyboard language. I had the same issue while using "U.S. International - PC" keyboard. When I changed to "US" it starts working with quotes as well.

Comment: Thank you! Made me crazy. Worked for me on MacOS.